# How do I prevent overlaps for 'get related content' in a Masonry Grid?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, masonry

I have a working '$related = get_posts' masonry on a single.php page. I also added a hover overlay, so that when the user hovers on the thumbnail, a transparent overlay appears as well as the descriptions (title name, category and nickname).

The problem I am facing is that when I hover on **one** related post thumbnail, the overlay appears for every post (*the overlay is stretched, it is not appearing individually*). I've also attempted to call out the descriptions, but it's only calling the current post I am viewing (*e.x. the current single.php header says Snow, when I hover the first related post, it also calls out the description for Snow*), however, if you click on the first related post thumbnail, it takes you to a different article (*it is not calling the description for the different article*).

```
<div class="related">
    <h3>Related</h3>
    <div class="js-masonry">
        <div class="overlay">
            <?php $related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'orderby' => 'rand', 'numberposts' => 3, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
            if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) { setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,300)); ?></a>
            <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <div class="posts">
            <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name . ' ';}?>
          <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
          ————
          <h4><?php the_author();?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the title says, how do I pull the correct description and overlay for one post via hover for ' $related = get_posts' on the single.php page in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by reorganizing the code correctly.

```
<div class="js-masonry">   
    <?php $args = array(
    'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories( get_queried_object_id() ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post__not_in' => array( get_queried_object_id() )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="item-masonry overlay">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
        <div class="posts">
            <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name . ' ';}?> 
            <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
            ————
            <h4><?php the_author();?></h4>
        </div>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,300)); ?>
    </div>
    </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```